# How can I extract the numerical prefix of a string using REGEX_EXTRACT on Hive?

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I'm not sure how to write my regex command on Hive to pull the numerical prefix substring from this string: 211118-1_20569 - (DHCP). I need to return 211118, but also have the flexibility to return digits with smaller or larger values depending on the size of the numerical prefix.

Comment: by prefix, do you mean everything before the first `-` character?

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> select regexp_extract('211118-1_20569 - (DHCP)','^\\d+',0);
OK
211118
```

or

```
hive> select regexp_extract('211118-1_20569 - (DHCP)','^[0-9]+',0);
OK
211118
```

---

```
^     - The beginning of a line
\d    - A digit: [0-9]
[0-9] - the characters between '0' and '9'
X+    - X, one or more times
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

---

```
regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)
```

- predefined character classes (e.g. `\d`) should be preceded with additional backslash (`\\d`)
- index = 0 matches the whole pattern

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators

Comment: You still haven't explained how this answers the question. Don't just say "this code works"; explain how it solves the problem and what it does.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, It was already pass midnight. The explanations could wait for the morning and meanwhile the OP could continue with his work.

Comment: that's fair enough, but in that case it's customary to add a note saying as much -- "It's late here; I'll explain in the morning." Also, I was replying to a comment of yours that, without context, appeared to be saying that the post was fixed; given that I was pretty tired when I wrote that, I think I misunderstood it.